# After clicking the submit button, model does not seem to receive the data from the inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am doing a course, and i have everything just like the "teacher", but when I try to do the login form it doesn't work. I find already like 3 problems with my form.

1. Doesn't show the span when input boxes are empty.
2. When posting data, model seems to not receiving the data.

   [Form with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0dn5.png)

   [After submiting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFfu4.png)
3. Doesn't show the alerts.

Here is the model:

```
public class UsuarioM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El usuario es obligatorio")]
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La contraseña es obligatoria")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "La contraseña debe tener entre 4 a 10 caracteres")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        UsuarioM usuario = new UsuarioM();
        return View(usuario);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UsuarioM usuario)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UsuarioM user = await _cuentaRepositorio.IngresarAsync(Constantes.rutaUsuario + "Login", usuario);
            if (user.Token == null)
            {
                TempData["alert"] = "Los datos son incorrectos";
                return View();
            }
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usuario.Usuario));
            
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
            
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("JWToken", user.Token);
            TempData["alert"] = $"Bienvenido {user.Usuario}";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Razor view:

```
@model PeliculasWeb.Models.UsuarioM
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1 class="text-center">Acceso de usuarios</h1>

<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        @if (TempData["alert"] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <h5><strong>@TempData["alert"]</strong></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 offset-3">
        <form asp-action="Login">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Usuario">Usuario:</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="Usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa el usuario" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Usuario" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contrasenia">Contraseña:</label>
                <input type="password" asp-for="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa la contraseña" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">INGRESAR</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried doing again the view and the model, but nothing seems to change.

For now I think that the main problem is something about the model, but I don't have any idea what could it be, and in case you are asking, this same code works on the course :c, also I have other models and views and they work fine, I don't know what's happening here. And I already did the question in the course, but I'm not getting answers and I really need to finish it quickly.

Also in case there are like grammatical mistakes or things like that I apologize, I'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your parameter name `UsuarioM usuario` here conflicts with the property name `Usuario` in the model.

Just change the parameter name to be different from the property name, for example like below `UsuarioM model`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UsuarioM model)
```

Comment: You are right!!! it was that!!!. ahhhh!! thank you, now it show the alerts and also the model requiered comment, well it does the method. you saved me from wasting more time. thanks

Comment: Also, why was this the problem? I don't get it

Comment: Hi @EduardoMeza, because model binding binds the property by name.

Answer (score 0):

First off the tag

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

When you use this tag you are telling the server it should verify that a token is to be sent in your form, I don't see it.

You need to add

```
<form>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
...
</form>
```

Also this model comming into the function

```
UsuarioM
```

This model has variable id, and token that are also not in your form.
I would add

```
<input />
```

for all variables in the object you will be sending. If you don't want to see the inputs then use type="hidden".

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

in the **Controller** File Add `[BindProperty]` and `TempData["alert"]` and create a `property` :

```
[BindProperty] //This will help to bind data automatically
public UsuarioM usuario { get; set; } //Create this property

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    UsuarioM usuario = new UsuarioM();
    TempData["alert"] = "write your alert message here"; //To show the aler
    return View(usuario);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login() //No need to pass the property as a parameter
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Magic...
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

in **RazorView** replace:

```
<form method="Post" asp-action="Login">
     <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Usuario">Usuario:</label>
          <input type="text" asp-for="usuario.Usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa el usuario" />
          <span asp-validation-for="usuario.Usuario" class="text-danger"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="contrasenia">Contraseña:</label>
          <input type="password" asp-for="usuario.Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa la contraseña" />
          <span asp-validation-for="usuario.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">INGRESAR</button>
</form>
```

in the View I replaced :

`<form asp-action="Login">` with `<form method="Post" asp-action="Login">`

`asp-for="Usuario"` with `asp-for="usuario.Password"`

`asp-validation-for="Usuario"` with `asp-validation-for="usuario.Usuario"`

`asp-for="Password"` with `asp-for="usuario.Password"`

`asp-validation-for="Password"` with `asp-validation-for="usuario.Password"`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the [BindProperty] it also give me a clue of what was the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `asp-action="Login" method="post"` to your form element. Everything else is correct. I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Well guys, the problem was that I called the model the same way as I called it in the get method (I didn't think that would be a problem), so I just have to change that and now it works correctly.

Before:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    UsuarioM usuario = new UsuarioM();
    return View(usuario);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UsuarioM usuario)
```

Now:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        UsuarioM usuario = new UsuarioM();
        return View(usuario);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UsuarioM usuarioP)
```

I really thanks for all the answers, now I know a little bit more things, so thank you all guys :)